# Saving view to different schema using QGIS DB manager?

Tags: qgis, dbmanager

When I ask to save a query to a view QGIS pops up a dialogue box asking the for a name and then saves the view in the public schema with that name.  I have tried "layers.name" but this just puts "layers." in front of the name and saves it in public.

The only way I have found to get the views created in the layers schema is to use postgres directly.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write the CREATE VIEW part into the SQL input box instead of clicking the create view button. With the button, it's always put into public. (I might have seen a ticket related to this issue somewhere ...) If CREATE VIEW is simply specified in the SQL statement, the view is created in the specified schema.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. DB Manager needs some polishing.